How do I do error handling for my website deployment which uses AWS Elastic beanstalk (Error 503)
I have an asp.net-mvc code and when I run it on localhost it works but when I deploy it using AWS Elastic beanstalk it display an error message:

and I tried checking the console and it displays:

is there anyway to do error handling to find the problem and fix it?
